# Magento 2 : Creating widget using install script

Tags: magento2, extensions, install-script, upgrade-script, widget-instance

I have a custom module for megamenu. I want to create some widgets predefined for the module when the customer installs this module. I have added the below script for creating the widget(widget type: cms block)

This is my InstallData.php

```
namespace Vendor\MegaMenu\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup;

class InstallData implements Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Setup\SampleData\Executor
     */
    protected $executor;
    /**
     * @var Installer
     */
    protected $installer;

    private $widgetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Setup\SampleData\Executor $executor, 
        Installer $installer,
        \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\InstanceFactory $widgetFactory
        )
    {
        $this->executor = $executor;
        $this->installer = $installer;
        $this->widgetFactory = $widgetFactory;
    }

    public function install(Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, Setup\ModuleContextInterface $moduleContext)
    {
        $this->executor->exec($this->installer);

        $megaMenuWidget = [
            'instance_type' => 'Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block',
            'theme_id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Test Megamenu Horizontal',
            'store_ids' => '0',
            'widget_parameters' => 'a:1:{s:8:"block_id";s:1:"11";}',
            'sort_order' => 1
        ];

        $this->widgetFactory->create()->setData($megaMenuWidget)->save();

    }

}
```

The widget is created. But not able to set layout update field and assign static block. Please refer the screenshot

http://i.prntscr.com/NEp1Nu_wToOwDCJYlQR_-g.png

How can I create a widget using upgrade script? My Magento version is 2.1.x

Please help me with a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **This worked for me please try it**.

```
$megaMenuWidget = [
    'instance_type' => 'Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block',
    'theme_id' => 2,
    'title' => 'Test Megamenu Horizontal',
    'store_ids' => '0',
    'widget_parameters' => 'a:1:{s:8:"block_id";s:1:"11";}',
    'sort_order' => 1,
    'page_groups' => [[
        'page_group' => 'all_pages',
        'all_pages' => [
            'page_id' => null,
            //'group' => 'all_pages',
            'layout_handle' => 'default',
            'block' => 'top.container',
            'for' => 'all',
            'template' => 'widget/static_block/default.phtml'
        ]
    ]]
];
```

Comment: can u confirm the widget can able to display config products?

Comment: @jafarpinjar check this one - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344187/57644

Answer (score 0):

**This will work for catalog product list type widgets:**

```
$catalogProductListWidget = [
        'instance_type' => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\Product\CustomProductList', // widget.xml block class
        'instance_code' => 'custom_product_items_widget', //widget.xml id
        'theme_id' => 7, //admin theme edit id
        'title' => 'CUSTOM ITEMS AVAILABLE',
        'store_ids' => '2,5', //admin store edit id
        'widget_parameters' => '{"title":"CUSTOM ITEMS AVAILABLE",'.
            '"show_buttons":["add_to_cart","add_to_wishlist"],"cache_lifetime":"",'.
            '"conditions":{"1":{"type":"Magento\\\CatalogWidget\\\Model\\\Rule\\\Condition\\\Combine",'.
            '"aggregator":"all","value":"1","new_child":""}}}',
        'sort_order' => 1,
        'page_groups' => [[
            'page_id' => 1,
            'page_group' => 'all_products',
            'layout_handle' => 'catalog_product_view',
            'for' => 'all',
            'all_products' => [
                'page_id' => null,
                'layout_handle' => 'catalog_product_view',
                'block' => 'product.info.extrahint', // widget.xml containers
                'for' => 'all',
                'template' => 'Vendor_Module::product/widget/content/grid.phtml' // widget template phtml
            ]
        ]]
    ];
```