# How to create widget programmatically in magento 2.x.x?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have some widget in custom theme and that theme should be imported automatically.
-> after click on import button all the required widget, blocks and pages will be installed in back end. I had already done with block and pages but I need to do it for widget now.
Its really appreciated, If anyone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Follow this link https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-widget/ or this one https://magenticians.com/create-widget-in-magento-2/

Comment: can you please provide me xml parameters, to add already created CMS static block into widget??

Comment: It is possible to create new widget with Setup Script (see link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221967/magento-2-creating-widget-using-install-script), but this solution creates only entry in **widget_instance** table without creating entry in **widget_instance_page**. You need add some changed in Admin

Answer (score 0):

this link help to create and get some idea about create widget and how it work.
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-widget/